# Geokit ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `within`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, geokit

In my `Firm` class I have

```
acts_as_mappable :lat_column_name => :latitude,
                 :lng_column_name => :longitude
```

I'm trying to test geokit. I assign `f = Firm.first` and run

```
Firm.within(5, f)
```

> Error: "ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `within`"

Comment: What db are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have a field named `within` in your table `firm` or a method with this name in your model ?

Comment: No, I do not have this.

Comment: You should have defined `within`somewhere. In this case it's probably why it return an error.
Try to add this field in your table.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do. The gem should find me X objects "within" Y range.